# Next Auth: Extending User schema to include new fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I have a typescript application with Next Auth v4 that's using GithubProvider + MongoDBAdapter (this way I have access to the database documents User, Profile and Account).

The problem is that I need to add a new field to User schema, for example the `role` field.

The majority of results that I found online point that in v4 you need profile a function `profile` to your provider.

And so I did! This is my [...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import { MongoDBAdapter } from '@next-auth/mongodb-adapter'
import connectDB from 'lib/mongooseConnect'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

connectDB()

export const authOptions = {
   // Configure one or more authentication providers
   providers: [
      GithubProvider({
         clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
         clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
         //@ts-ignore
         profile(profile) {
            return {
               id: profile.id,
               name: profile.name,
               email: profile.email,
               image: profile.avatar_url,
               role: 'USER',
            }
         },
      }),
      // ...add more providers here
   ],
   adapter: MongoDBAdapter(
      new Promise((resolve) => resolve(mongoose.connection.getClient()))
   ),
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

This allowed me to populate a default field in User document... but when I try to access it by `session.user.role` I get a TS error as an undefined result.

For example, this code doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import useProfileByOwner from 'hooks/api/useProfileByOwner'
import { IProfile } from 'models/Profile'

const UserContext = React.createContext<Value>({
   profile: undefined,
   isSelected: undefined,
})

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const { data: session } = useSession()
   const { data: ownProfile } = useProfileByOwner(session?.user?.email)
   const router = useRouter()

   //@ts-ignore
   const isSelected =
      router.query.slugOrId === ownProfile?.slug ||
      router.query.slugOrId === ownProfile?._id ||
      //@ts-ignore
      session?.user?.role === 'ADMIN'

   return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ profile: ownProfile, isSelected }}>
         {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
   )
}

type Value = {
   profile: IProfile
   isSelected: boolean
}

export default UserContext
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for adding a user role field in the collection, you may do. Update the user schema with user role. Then add a custom callback in `[...nextauth]`.

```js
callbacks: {
   session({ session, token, user }) {
   session.user.role = user.role; //  Add role value to user object so it is passed along with session            
   return session;
  }
}
```

Then you may call session in your pages.

```js
if (session && session.user.role === "admin") {
   return (...)
 }
```

Check out this reference:- [**Reference**](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/role-based-login-strategy).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're wanting to [Extend default interface properties](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#extend-default-interface-properties).

> By default, TypeScript will merge new interface properties and overwrite existing ones. In this case, the default session user properties will be overwritten, with the new one defined above.

You'll need to *declare* the type extension in order for TypeScript to recognize `session.user.role` as a valid field.

```
// ./types/nextauth.d.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
    interface Session {
        user: {
            role: string;
        } & DefaultSession['user'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I've had to deal with this same issue, out of completeness and building upon [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77596296/941770), here's a complete example so that the TS compiler will fully comply:

```
// types/next-auth.d.ts
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: {
      /** The user's role. */
      role: string
    } & DefaultSession["user"]
  }
  interface User {
    role: string
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  /** Returned by the `jwt` callback and `getToken`, when using JWT sessions */
  interface JWT {
    /** The user's role */
    role: string
  }
}
```